# Calling StopSelfResult on JobService

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, job-scheduling

What are the repercussions of calling `stopSelf(startId)` or `stopSelfResult(startId)` on a JobService. Yes, I could call `jobFinished`. But humor me. What would happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JobService` is a [bound service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and `stopSelf`/`stopSelfResult` only apply to [started Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingAService) so nothing will happen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was suspecting this but other than the `public final IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder.asBinder();
    }` portion, I couldn't tell for sure that it is never started. But I suppose since they never explicitly use `onStartCommand` then that seals the argument.